# I want to create a module in prestashop which saves a text in the database

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I want to create a module to save a comment for a order, but I don't know where to insert the code that handles the form from the TPL file.

The contents of my `ordercomments.php` file are:

```
public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params){
    return $this->display(__FILE__,    'views/templates/admin/ordercomments.tpl');
}

public function getContent()
{
    $output = null;
    $comment = null;

    if (Tools::isSubmit('addOrderNote'))
    {
        $comment = Tools::getValue('order_comment');

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'order_comment' => $comment,
        ));
    }

    return $output.$this->displayForm();
}
```

I have the following in my `ordercomments.tpl` file:

```
<div class="row" id="ordercomments">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form action="{$link->getAdminLink('ordercomments','AdminOrderCommentsController',array_of_params)|escape:'htmlall':'utf-8'}" method="post">
            <input class="button btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" name="addOrderNote" id="addOrderNote" value="{l s='Add note' mod='ordercomments'}" style="float:right; margin-top:15px; ">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code to handle the form data in postProcess() function AdminOrdersController.php controller. You can use following code:

if (Tools::isSubmit('anyFormInputName') && isset($order)) {

-- Your Code Here --

}

If this doesn't work then try the same AdminOrderMessageController.php controller.